# Web site as image/clip art library with reference?

Tags: html, image, web

As a software developer, I have done many web page applications and been doing blog for my programming experiences. I would like to use pictures in many cases. **Pictures worth thousand words and they are universal language**!

You could create your own clip art images or download graphics(actually many are open clip art/image libraries available, [Open Clip Art Library](http://openclipart.org/media/view/media/home) as example). However your time and art skill are limited and you can only keep limited library of images.

I wish if there is any open art/image library web sites with permanent references available so that you just add a simple reference in your html page like this just like a way that you could use other people or web site's graphics:

```
<img src="http://OpenArtLibray.net/icon/work/DoItYourself.png".../>
```

In this way, there is no need to waste time to download and upload images and no waste on your and other computer's disk spaces(no duplication). Just one place with a huge amount of variety of images available, and open for people to use, or with some reasonable fees. People may vote the popularity of art/images as well.

Is there any such kind of web site available?

Answer (score 1):

Typically sites discourage this.  What this really does is shift the bandwidth cost to the hosting site.  There have been cases where sites with pictures have analyzed the referrer to determine if images are linked to from other sites, then servering an image with text claiming the image is being 'stolen'.

The point of that, is the idea isn't very well liked.

However, some sites like w3c, allow you to link to their certification images.  It all depends on what you are linking to.

It is hard to think of a business doing this, as there doesn't seem to be a revenue aspect.

Even if some were charged fees, there's a lot of work involved in checking/verifying who has paid, via referrer texts.  Maybe you have a new business plan.

Update:
Oh, I have a friend who always sends me emails with links to flickr.  Maybe their license lets you link to images on their site.  Something for you to check out.

Update:
This text, "photo hosting sites", makes for an interesting, relevant google search.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for [Chris](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15578/chris) explanation. I could accept it as a answer. However, I raised this question because I really don't like to "steal" images. I can see it is hard to charge fees, but there are some many open resources available on the web. Actually, I found one [Open Clip Art Library](http://openclipart.org/media/view/media/home), which allow people to contribute and share images. I found many good pictures there and downloaded. I may contribute some when I create images for my blog so I'll let people to use my.

Flickre is an open social place for people store and sharing pictures. As long as pictures are shared there, specially by people, I think you can use and link images there. Still you have to do the work: creating and uploading. Actually, I tried another open social site called as [DropBox](https://www.getdropbox.com/home). I can create a public folder there and add my pictures for sharing. All those sites have one common problem: personal account and may not be available if inactive for certain period of time (90 days for DropBox?).

That's why I asked this question here in StackOverFlow. I hope some people may know some hosts available or any other alternative options available. Maybe it is just like Chris said, "the idea isn't very well liked".

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I realize that Open Clip Art Library I mentioned in my previous email does provide image hosting-like service. If you click on any one's picture download link, it will open a new tab or window to display the graphic. The display has its URL. I have created a new user name and submitted my picture. It works well. I can include the graphics in my test web page. Not sure how long the URL will be there. It looks like permanent one.

Answer (score 0):

Try [searching Creative Commons licensed](http://search.creativecommons.org/) works. People will often upload and share photos on such places as Flickr under a Creative Commons license which allows you to remix, reference or use on your own projects, blogs or site.

There are different types of licenses under the CC with some asking you to not use their works if you're going to be making money from it or if you're engaging in commercial activity.

You just have to nod back to the original author when using items under CC and if you link back to them, that's just good karma.